# UITableView does not request cell height when keyboard is displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

The issue is that the UITableView stops asking the UITableViewDelegate's heightForRowAtIndexPath for what the height of the row should be when a UITextField has first responder in an existing row.

The UITableView is constructed with three sections.  Each section has a unique row height such that the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` appears similar to the following:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.Section == 0)
        return [tableView rowHeight];
    else if (indexPath.Section == 1)
        return 88.0;
    else if (indexPath.Section == 2)
        return 155.0;
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is similar, configuring a different type of custom UITableViewCell depending on which section is being asked for.

This works all fine and dandy until one of the many UITextFields within Section 2 is editing.  Then when the user presses the insert row for Section 1 all of the cells are animated back to the iOS default height for rows and our implementation of `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is no longer being called.

Through experimentation I believe it may have something to do with how we ensure the different text fields in each row are kept visible above the keyboard.  The controller is subscribed to keyboard willShow and willHide events while keeping track of which field is touched.  The implementation of willShow calls `scrollRectToVisible` giving the converted frame of the UITextField.

Comment: Please post your attempted solution.

Comment: I am not sure as to what you want when asking for an attempted solution.  There is only the problem and no solution currently.  I can add some pseudo code for the situation if you would like.

Comment: I'm saying your question is too vague to get a good answer.  You could start by showing your implementation of `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and `viewDidLoad`, for example.  Whatever you think might be relevant.

Comment: Sorry the question appears vague.  I'm not allowed to post any of the actual code so I tried to describe the situation.  I will edit to try and improve the description and will add some pseudo-code of how things are laid out.

Comment: Why don't you create a new, separate project that reproduces the issue with minimum code, and post that?

Comment: I will work on trying to reproduce this in a simple project.  Though I have low hopes because most of the issues in the app are a direct result of the size of the app.  Aside, I have made some edits that I hope explain the issue better.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue based on the information you've provided.

Comment: This issue happens on iOS 11 devices only. I'm also trying to find a way to fix the issue, any updates?